# Do s40 with themes jar has a bug that textarea is not getting scrolled in it?

Tags: java-me, nokia-s40

I am making s40 app and done all my coding using s40 with themes jar file. I used this jar because of gesture available in it. But my textarea is not getting scrolled in it.
Anybody used it so far for scrolling textarea?
Plz help

Answer (score 0):

which user interface? I think textarea is for lwuit. Again, what is the size of your app?  If too large, then it will be susceptible to hanging hence scrolling problem. J2ME tutorial at http://www.tutorialmasterng.blogspot.com

Comment: Hi, ya textarea i m using is for s40 with themes jar... it is basically lwuit only with biult in theme. But even if i make a demo program still textarea is not scrolling in it . Hence i guess jar size is not the problem. What could be the reason? I am making my app in nokia sdk 2.0 for asha 310 phones and using lwuit forms in it